# Retrieve Input from PowerShell TextBox

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

I am working on a PowerShell application which should take a user id as input from a text box, then search ActiveDirectory and return three fields; however, every time I try to use it I receive the following error:

```
Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At C:\Path\cc-lookup-gui.ps1:40 char:21
+     $y = Get-ADUser $script:x -Properties cC
+                     ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Here is the code for my GUI and search function:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")|Out-Null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")|Out-Null
$net = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Network


$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Width = 525
$form.Height = 350
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::Fixed3D
$form.Text = "CC Lookup"
$form.MaximumSize = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(525,350)
$form.StartPosition = "centerscreen"
$form.KeyPreview = $true
$form.Add_KeyDown({if($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter"){$script:x=$input.Text;Search}})
$form.Add_KeyDown({if($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape"){$form.Close()}})

$input = new-object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$input.maxLength = 6
$input.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,75)


add-type -assemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,25)
$label1.AutoSize = $true
$label1.Text = "Enter User ID:"

$Button1 = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,132)
$Button1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,20)
$Button1.Text = "Search"
$Button1.Add_Click({$script:x=$input.Text;Search})

$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,132)
$button2.Text = "Clear"
$button2.Add_Click({Clears})

function Search{
    $y = Get-ADUser $script:x -Properties cC
    $output = $y.samAccountName + '|' + $y.CN + '|' + $y.cC
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Text = $Output
    $label.AutoSize = $true
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,100)
    $form.controls.add($label)
}

function Clears{
    $label.Text = $null
    $input.Text = $null
}

$form.Controls.Add($label1)
$form.Controls.Add($button2)
$form.Controls.Add($input)
$form.Controls.Add($Button1)
$form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
$Form.ShowDialog()
$x = $input.Text
```

I have tried declaring the variable `$x` globally, directly calling `$input.text` for the search function, and converting `$x` into a string, all of which return this same error. I'm running PowerShell version 5.

Comment: Both of your buttons fail.  I'd start with that.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, that was the issue. If you post that as an answer I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$Input` is a special variable name - see [help about_Automatic_Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) - and won't do what you expect when you use it in your `{}` scriptblock, it will refer to scriptblock input (in this case, nothing), instead of your inputbox.

Try renaming it to something else.